# .net 6.0 API WebApplication builder not recognizing extension

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I'm following along with the tutorial at [c-sharpcorner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-token-authentication-and-authorizations-in-net-core-6-0-web-api/) to add JWT authentication and running into an issue. I've re-done the entire tutorial and come up with the same issue in the same place.

After adding the extension class `AddJWTTokenServicesExtensions` in the `MyApplication.Extensions` namespace, and constructing the builder in Program.cs via `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);`, `buider.Services` is not recognizing the method `AddJWTTokenServices`

```
builder.Services.AddJWTTokenServices(builder.Configuration);
```

Error:

```
'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddJWTTokenServices' and no accessible extension method 'AddJWTTokenServices' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Is the tutorial wrong in extending the class, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I'd say the obvious problem is following an article from c-sharpcorner, but... The error is that you did not add a `using MyApplication.Extensions;`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm open to better tutorials, but I do have `using MyApplication.Extensions` (I know to do that much lol)

Comment: Ah, the tutorial has another typo: `public static void AddJWTTokenServices(IServiceCollection Services,` -> lacks `this`, should be `public static void AddJWTTokenServices(this IServiceCollection Services,`

Comment: I have seen this article and there is better way to add jwt authentication. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: @variable I'm just trying to set up user authentication/session for an API app. Been away from C# for like a year and this is my first jaunt into .net 6

Comment: I have just done this yesterday and I will shortly give you a simpler example.

Comment: Follow this one: https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/jwt-authentication-in-asp-net-core-web-api-82895c29734c

Comment: @variable is there a way I can contact you?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: @variable I just have too many dumb questions to post here, will gladly pay someone to answer via email or something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241037/discussion-between-variable-and-randy-hall).

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `this` in the constructor like so:

```
public static void ConfigureMailService(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you can only use `this` in extension methods, not constructors. Furthermore, `AddJWTTokenServices` is part external library, and not yours to edit (AND it's an extension method). Apart from that, why are you answering a >2 year old question? I don't think the OP needs help anymore. Please read [answer]